# Problem submitting a html form to itself using AJAX and button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to write a php page which will do the following,

1. contains an input form,
2. submit the data to the same php page using AJAX
3. does some mysql insert stuff (not included in the following code)
4. echo the mysql results in another div item of the same php

As it is right now I have several problems:

1. When the form is submitted, the results are not placed in the "submission_result" div area, and instead refreshes the page. I was hoping the form is still visible after submission.
2. if one of the required fields is not filled, the default error message pops up and the box goes red but the form is still submitted, I was hoping the submission would be blocked. It loads the page again and place in in the "submission_result" div area (which is kind of what I want but only when the form is correctly filled).
3. In order to stop the whole page refreshes, I tried using event.preventDefault function, which doesn't solve all the issues ... :-(

I suppose I can avoid using the button tag but it has the nice "required fields" check, and arrange the data in $_POST automatically, which would save me coding those parts.

Here is my code

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<?php
    echo "<div id='input_form'>";

    if ( empty($_POST) )
    {
        echo "<h4>Submitting a new article:</h4>";
        echo "<form action='test_sub.php' id='submission_form' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
        echo "<p> Title: </br><input type='text' id='title' name='title' value='test' required> </p>";
        echo "<p> url: </br><input type='url' id='url' name='url' > </p>";
        echo "</ul>";
        echo "<p> content: </br><textarea rows='5' id='content' name='article_content' required>hello world</textarea></br>";
        echo "<button class='sub_button' id='btn_sub_button' >Submit</button>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Input data";
        echo count($_POST);
        var_dump($_POST);
        /*
         * mysql insert ... etc
         * catch exception ... etc
        */ 
    }
    echo "</div>";

    echo "</br>";
    echo "</br>";

    echo "<div id='submission_result'>";
    echo "Submission result 1</br>";
    echo "Submission result 2</br>";
    echo "Submission result 3</br>";
    echo "</div>";

?>

<script>
      $(document).ready(function()
    {
          $("#btn_sub_button").click(function(){
                //event.preventDefault();
                $('#submission_result').load("test_sub.php");
                        });
    });
</script>
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Where is your closing form tag (</form>) ?

Comment: Guess I forgot that thanks ... ^^!, but adding it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: you used event.preventDefault() on button clicked how it will prevent form submission?

Comment: @AmitSingh I tried both with and without event.preventDefault(). But it doesn't solve my problems. I wonder if I can only prevent the refreshing aspect.

Comment: Did you said ajax, now where if your ajax here. I think you are implementing something before going through the doc

Comment: @AkhilAravind the ajax is in $('#submission_result').load("test_sub.php");

Comment: have you tried by passing an **argument** in  function(event) `$("#btn_sub_button").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();`

Comment: @luiluilui, please go through the simple implementation examples, 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp

Comment: @luiluilui and you havn't use AJAX in your page...

Comment: @AkhilAravind I'm pretty sure it's related to submitting through button as well, because the page works if submit using a div instead. But then I'll have to code the form validation stuff myself.

Comment: @luiluilui **Advice to you :** First complete the basic concepts of AJAX with Javascript intead of Jquery, and when you feel you have done then give online quiz on what have you learned previously.

Comment: @AbhishekKamal maybe I mistaken what's AJAX, but according to W3 school .load() is an AJAX method. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp

Comment: @luiluilui we need to decide what method to use before implementing, `.load()` and `.get()` and `.post()`, and `.ajax()` are ajax methods and we need to use them as our need.

Comment: @AbhishekKamal I'm not sure if this is an AJAX problem, because the code would work if I only change the above code from  `$("#btn_sub_button").click` to `$("#submission_result").click`. So while I might not understand AJAX completely, it's more of a problem with using **button**, but the AJAX part works otherwise.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function()
    {
          $("#btn_sub_button").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                
                $("#submission_result").load('test_sub.php',$("#submission_form").serializeArray());
                        });
    });` first use this code to solve the reloading problem and get the result.

Comment: @AbhishekKamal Thanks, that does seem to solve the refreshing problem, cheers!! Do you know can I retain the function of default form validation function as well? Thanks.

Comment: Yes its very easy to add some validations to filter the form-data. **Take tutorals and learn**

Comment: @AbhishekKamal Yea, I know how to validate the form using the tutorial methods, just wondering if there's a way to utilize the button's default after event.preventDefault() **as I have stated in my original post**. No point doing it again if it's already there.

Comment: @luiluilui I added an answer and please tell here, if you got what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
$('form').on('submit',function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    //write your ajax here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

According to above conversation, I reached to this -
So please replace you script with given below script.

````
<script>
    let count = 1; // to count the number of results
    let data = []; // for getting result with key value pair

      $(document).ready(function() { $("#btn_sub_button").click(function(event){ event.preventDefault();
        // getting form data as array with key value pair.
        let form_data = $("#submission_form").serializeArray();

        for(let i= 0; i< form_data.length; i++){
            data[form_data[i].name] = form_data[i].value;
        }

        $("#submission_result").append('<p><b><mark>Result ' + count +' = </b>' + '<b> Title :</b>'+data.title + ',<b> url : </b>'+ data.url + ',<b> article content: </b>' +data.article_content + '<p>');
        count++;
        //Add your AJAX code
        });

      });
</script>```
````

Comment: @luiluilui First Use above code without adding the AJAX to understand what is happening.

Comment: that's not quite what I want, but I really appreciate your help. Thank you very much. But I need to prepare my family for the coronavirus outbreak now :-(

Comment: You told me that you want to  **utilize the button's default after event.preventDefault()**. so in my answer you can utilize the button again and again and get the result each and every time without refresing the page. but if you want to add the form data to the database then you need to add AJAX too. My answer is just an example to help you to grab the inserted form data.